# Why has my collegue network access to my harddrive c?

Tags: windows, networking, hard-drive, network-shares

When I add the address **\\collegue-a\c$** to my Explorer I have access to the harddrive of my collegue. If he does the same (by replacing collegue-a with my pc name) he has access to my harddrive. Neither of us has shared drive C explicitly.

I have Windows 8 and my collegue has Window 7.

What goes wrong? How can we protect? Is that wanted by our admins?

Comment: Have you disabled file sharing?

Comment: Related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share

Comment: Your admin would want to access your C drive at least from his computer(remotely). It is possible to set the windows firewall to block everybody off but your admin won't want that.  It is possible to block everybody off except your admin's computer, only allowing your admin access. Whether you want to do that yourself(and probably get it wrong, possibly annoying the admin), or asking somebody technical at the office to do that(possibly annoying the admin)  or asking your admin about the possibility of him setting your comp up like that(though he may say no for some odd reason)

Comment: you could just leave it.. ubless you can imagine some technical colleagues going through your office computer doing something malicious, but that's not likely, it's probably not worth it for them, they might get caught doing it. In fact, you're more at risk if you let the cat too far out of the bag to all your colleagues that they can access each others computers!

Answer (score 5):

C$ are default shares made by Windows for things such as access for PSExec. To disable it, change the following registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\AutoShareServer
```

to 0. Then restart the service, running the commands

```
net stop server
net start server
```

It is not recommended at all to disable these shares as they can break several things. To look at what these things are, go [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;842715). I would definitely say your admins want these to be set up.

Comment: If I understand it right my Sysadmin would not be amused if I "disable $C". Am I right that I have admin rights for the pc of my collegue?

Comment: The admin wouldn't be amused! You do not have admin rights to the PC, just access to the C drive. They're 2 different things